# Jquery Pjax - Ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

Currently I am translating my ajax calls to regular `$.pjax()` call. Everything works fine but ajax success function. I can't manage how to call pjax success function with given parameters.

The only thing I can use is defining pjax global success function to be called on each pjax call:

```
   $(document).on('pjax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr, options) {

   });
```

But unfortunately I would like to define per call specific success function.

Ajax call example:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"/myPage/myFunction",
    type:"POST",
    data:giveMeData(),
    success:function(data){$('#right_form').html(data);console.log('Success works!')}
 });
```

Pjax call example:

```
 $.pjax({
    url:"/myPage/myFunction",
    type:"POST",
    container:'#right_form',
    data:giveMeData(),
    success:function(){console.log('Success works!')}
 });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe that the jQuery PJAX library supports passing a "success" function directly in to a $.pjax call, although I suspect you could work around this using the `$(document).on('pjax:success')` callback & its `options` attribute in order to achieve the same functionality.

For example, say your request is like the above, but you want to have a custom success callback you could use something like this:

```
 $.pjax({
    url:"/myPage/myFunction",
    type:"POST",
    container:'#right_form',
    data:giveMeData(),
    custom_success:function(){console.log('Custom success works!')}
 });
```

Then, in order to run the `custom_success` method you could hook up the standard pjax success listener, and given that all the parameters provided to `$.pjax`  are made available in options, you can then grab `custom_success` function and run it. So your listener may look something like example

```
 $('#right_form').on('pjax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr, options) {
      // run "custom_success" method passed to PJAX if it exists
      if(typeof options.custom_success === 'function'){
           options.custom_success();
      }
 });
```

Which i *think* would provide the sort of functionality your after?

Comment: Yes, this is excactly what I was looking for. 

Other solution might be also using ".done(function(){console.log()})" postfix to each pjax call, but it doesnt apply on success listener probably.

One big "thank you" again :)

Comment: can anyone help me with this question?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122972/hide-jquery-elements-in-an-ajax-function

Answer (score 7):

A late answer but I found the solution [here](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/424).

```
$.pjax({
    url:"/myPage/myFunction",
    type:"POST",
    container:'#right_form',
    data:giveMeData(),        
 }).done(function() { console.log('Success works!') });
```